# Generate variables with Do loop?

Tags: loops, variables, vbscript

I have a `Do` loop in a VBS file and I need it to generate a variable every time it loops.
I can't figure out how to do this so I'll have to make incorrect syntax to try to show how it might work:

```
iteration = 0

do
  iteration = iteration+1
  variable & %iteration%

  if iteration = 55 then
    exit do
  end if
loop
```

I plan on setting each variable to a value inside the loop.  If this is impossible, what is the easiest way to generate the same number of variables as iterations in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the captain of your code, use an array:

```
>> ReDim a(2)
>> For i = 0 To UBound(a) : a(i) = i : Next
>> WScript.Echo Join(a)
>> WScript.Echo a(0), a(2), a(1)
>>
0 1 2
0 2 1
```

or - perhaps - a dictionary:

```
>> Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> For i = 0 To 2 : d(i) = i * 10 : Next
>> WScript.Echo d(1)
>>
10
```

If some other person sets the (bad) rules, you need [Execute[Global]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
>> i = 3
>> c = "var" & i & " = " & (i * 100)
>> WScript.Echo c
>> Execute c
>> WScript.Echo var3
>>
var3 = 300
300
```

Comment: Thanks, one of the best pieces of advice I've gotten on this site.  You're way cool